# Working out which folders are svn'd from the command line

Tags: svn

I've got a folder that containes a set of folders that are themselves the root of different projects. Some of these projects are versioned under svn, some are not.  I'm looking for a one-liner I can type on the command line to give me a list of those projects that arn't versioned… any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use 'svn info' to check if a sub directory is under version control. If the tested directory is not a working copy 'svn info' will return with error.
You can redirect output to hide the output of 'svn info'.

I will go on something like the following for iterating directories and if 'svn info' returns with error echo their name.

```
for D in */; do svn info ${D} &>/dev/null; if [  $? -ne 0 ]; then echo ${D}; fi done
```

I don't know if you can call it a one-liner but it'll do the work.
Also note that this does not include hidden directories.

Comment: Nice solution, but wouldn't it be slightly quicker to simply check if there's a `.svn` subdirectory in each location?

Comment: Works for me :)

Comment: @Lèsemajesté It will be, but the '.svn' can be old trash or something else and 'svn info' also validates the working copy to some extent.